# Django query - get parent object in annotated count filter

Tags: django, django-queryset, django-filter

I have 3 models:

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    username = models.CharField(db_index=True, max_length=20, unique = True)

class Content(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True) #User.content_set.all() returns all Content objects of the content
    contentURL = models.CharField(max_length=256, null=True)
    thumbnailURL = models.CharField(max_length=256, null=True, blank=True)
    second_content = models.OneToOneField('self', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True) #if this is not NULL, then the content has been uploaded with a second one and they form a pair to be retrieved together
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

class Fight(models.Model):
    win_content = models.ForeignKey(Content, db_index=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, related_name="wins", null=True) #Content.wins.all() returns all Fight objects of the content in which this content has won
    loss_content = models.ForeignKey(Content, db_index=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, related_name="losses", null=True) #Content.losses.all() returns all Fight objects of the content in which this content has lost
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)
    is_private = models.BooleanField(db_index=True, default=False) #we will filter those out for user quality calculations
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

I am trying to get:

1. All the `Content` where `second_content` is not null
2. Annotate each content with the related `Fight` count: once with wins, once with losses.

Here is my queryset:

```
contents = user.content_set.exclude(content__second_content=None).annotate(
    win_count=Count('wins', filter=Q(wins__loss_content=second_content)),
    loss_count=Count('losses', filter=Q(losses__win_content=second_content))
).order_by('-timestamp')
```

The problem is with `Q(wins__loss_content=second_content)`. `second_content` is not defined, because it refers to the `Fight` object, not to the parent. **How can I refer to the parent object?** I have tried `Q(wins__loss_content=content__second_content)` and it doesn't work either!

Comment: You can use an `F`-object here, so `Q(wins__loss_content=F('content__second_content'))`

Comment: Meh, this simple anwser is exactly what I needed! Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an [**`F`** object [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/expressions/#django.db.models.F) to refer to a field, for example `F('content')` thus refers to the foreign key field.

You can thus use that in an expression like:

```
contents = user.content_set.exclude(content__second_content=None).annotate(
    win_count=Count('wins', filter=Q(wins__loss_content=F('content'))),
    loss_count=Count('losses', filter=Q(losses__win_content=F('content')))
).order_by('-timestamp')
```

Note that here you count two separate `JOIN`s, so perhaps you should add set a [**`distinct=True`** parameter [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.Count.distinct) in your [**`Count(..)`** expression [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.Count) to avoid counting the same `wins` and `losses` twice.

Comment: Somehow I got mixed up with the referred object. The correct query I ended up with is: `contents = user.content_set.exclude(content__second_content=None).annotate(
win_count=Count('wins', filter=Q(wins__loss_content=F('content')), distinct=True),
loss_count=Count('losses', filter=Q(losses__win_content=F('content')), distinct=True)
)`
Btw thnx for the distinct tip, it did indeed not work properly without!